# Custom configuration in Load Test Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load, distributed-system

Instead of using wizard for Load test configuration, Can we do custom configuration through XML for Load testing in Visual Studio 2013? 
Like define Number of Virtual user, Concurrent executions etc...

Answer (score 0):

All the details of a load test can be modified via the "Properties" of each section. Access them from the context menus of the various pieces of a load test.

The ".loadtest" file contains XML and it can be edited with a text editor. The user load etc could be modified in this way. But **be very careful** as simple editing mistakes can make the file unreadable by Visual Studio.

Most aspects of a load test can be altered at run time by "plugins". These are well documented by Microsoft.

However, the normal method of altering the values and details of a load test  is via the Properties panels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you open your load test through file explorer in Notepad/Notepad++/your favourite XML editor, you will be able to edit your Load Test settings through the XML rather than the visual viewer through Visual Studio.

You can also do the above as @AdrianHHH has suggested. Once you have gone through the wizard once and created the Load Test, right clicking on various sections (Run Settings/Scenarios, etc.) allow you to open a properties section and edit all settings.